# Select PERIOD_BEGIN and PERIOD_END dates from historical data containing only timestamp in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, select, oracle11g

I've run into a bit of a problem. Background: I work as a business controller in a financial institution that offers wealth management services and it falls to me to do internal reporting on euros coming and going. As this is one of the KPIs used to evaluate managers' performance, I need to be able to report these numbers per manager. This bit is straightforward as each customer has a manager assigned to it. Now here's the fun thing - some questionable DW design choices were made in the past and the table containing the manager/customer relationship lacks all the relevant temporal information such as 'valid from' or 'valid until'. Basically it just stores the current state. Occasionally customers and portfolios get reassigned to other managers and this causes all the transaction done during the old manager's reign to show up as belonging to the new manager.

E.g. manager Joe is managing a customer called Blammo Ltd between January and March and the customer subscribes funds with 10 million $. Joe leaves the company and the customer gets assigned to manager Helen. During April the customer withdraws 5 mil. When I compile my reports at the end of April, Joe's KPI reads +-0 while Helen's shows +5 million while in truth it should tell Joe made 10 million and Helen lost 5.

We do have an audit table that contains all the rows from the table containing the manager/customer relationships and each row has a timestamp when it was created. What I hope to achieve is to build a view that uses these timestamps to build a table that has a **VALID_FROM** and **VALID_UNTIL** dates so I can easily assign transactions to specific managers by joining the transaction between the **VALID** dates.

So basically what I have is...

```
  CUSTOMERID   MANAGERID   TIMESTAMP   
 ------------ ----------- ------------ 
           1   A           01-01-2018  
           1   B           28-02-2018  
           1   A           31-05-2018  
           1   C           31-08-2018
```

And what I need is...

```
  CUSTOMERID   MANAGERID   VALID_FROM   VALID_UNTIL  
 ------------ ----------- ------------ ------------- 
           1   A           01-01-2018   28-02-2018   
           1   B           28-02-2018   31-05-2018   
           1   A           31-05-2018   31-08-2018   
           1   C           31-08-2018
```

What I've tried is

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMERID,
    MANAGERID,
    MIN(TIMESTAMP) AS VALID_FROM,
    MAX(TIMESTAMP) AS VALID_UNTIL
FROM CUSMAN.CUS_MAN_AUDIT
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMERID,
    MANAGERID
```

and this would work in a case where customers are never reassigned back to a previous manager. However due to maternal leaves etc. the customers get assigned back and forth between managers so the solution above won't produce correct result - joining a transaction made by customer '1' on '30-04-2018' to the customer/manager relationship data would produce two results - both managers A and B. Below is the table the query above would produce.

```
  CUSTOMERID   MANAGERID    VALID_FROM    VALID_UNTIL  
 ------------ ----------- -------------- ------------- 
           1   A           01-01-2018     31-08-2018   
           1   B           28-02-2018     31-05-2018   
           1   C           31-08-2018
```

It feels like there's a simple way to do this but I'm stumped. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Bloody 'ell, I forgot to mention that the table CUS_MAN_AUDIT also contains plenty of other columns, such as customer name, legal form etc and now Caius's answer returns a result set shown below (CUSTOMERNAME included for sake of clarity, not in actual result set)

`+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
| CUSTOMERID | MANAGERID | VALID_FROM | VALID_UNTIL | CUSTOMERNAME |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+
|          1 | A         | 01-01-2018 | 02-01-2018  | Blam-O Litnd |
|          1 | A         | 02-01-2018 | 15-01-2018  | Blamo Litd   |
|          1 | A         | 15-01-2018 | 28-02-2018  | Blammo Ltd   |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+--------------+`

while it should (or at least what I'd like it to)

`+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
| CUSTOMERID | MANAGERID | VALID_FROM | VALID_UNTIL |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+
|          1 | A         | 01-01-2018 | 28-02-2018  |
+------------+-----------+------------+-------------+`

And I can't remember how I formatted my tables in the original post, sorry...

Comment: You can't remember how you got the original code blocks because I did it :). Indent each line of the code block with 4 leading spaces rather than surrounding it in backticks `

Comment: Ah well, that explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a window function that gets the LEAD (next) value of the date, per customer, ordered by the timestamp

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMERID,
    MANAGERID,
    TIMESTAMP AS VALID_FROM,
    LEAD(TIMESTAMP) OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER ORDER BY TIMESTAMP) as VALID_TIL
FROM CUSMAN.CUS_MAN_AUDIT
```

If it aids your understanding it's functionally similar to this:

```
SELECT
    CUSTOMERID,
    MANAGERID,
    cur.TIMESTAMP AS VALID_FROM,
    MIN(nxt.TiMESTAMP) as VALID_TIL
FROM 
  CUSMAN.CUS_MAN_AUDIT cur
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  CUSMAN.CUS_MAN_AUDIT nxt
  ON
    cur.CUSTOMERID = nxt.CUSTOMERID AND
    cur.TIMESTAMP < nxt.TIMESTAMP
GROUP BY
    CUSTOMERID,
    MANAGERID,
    cur.TIMESTAMP
```

Joining the table back to itself on the same customer but where each cur record is associated with every record that has a later date (nxt) and then getting the MIN of the later dates..

Comment: Thanks for the help! Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that the audit table has additional columns not shown in my original post which somewhat changes the returned results

Comment: Use the first query, not the second. You can add as many columns as you like to the first one but you can't do it to the second because of grouping keys